# Delete All alarms with state

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to delete all the alarms with state (INSUFFICIENT_DATA or any other) using AWS SDK java ?

I donot see any methods here.

```
    AmazonCloudWatch cloudWatch = getAmazonCloudwatchClient();
    DeleteAlarmsRequest request = new DeleteAlarmsRequest();
```

Comment: Side-note: An alarm with a state of _INSUFFICIENT_DATA_ is not a bad thing. It simply means that it has not received data within the previous time period. This is quite common for services. For example, Amazon SQS does not send a message count when a queue is empty, so an alarm based on the message count would have a state of _INSUFFICIENT_DATA_. But it is still working fine.

Comment: You are right.. INSUFFICIENT_DATA was just an example. I am working in automating the recovery option for an Instance using cloudwatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this approach and it helps me.

```
  AmazonCloudWatch cloudWatch = getAmazonCloudwatchClient();
  List<MetricAlarm> alarmsList = new ArrayList<>();
    do {

        DescribeAlarmsResult result = describeAlarms(cloudWatch, nextToken);
        nextToken = result.getNextToken();
        alarmsList.addAll(result.getMetricAlarms());
    }
    while (nextToken != null);

    for(MetricAlarm alarm : alarmsList){
        DeleteAlarmsRequest request = new DeleteAlarmsRequest();
        request.withAlarmNames(alarm.getAlarmName());
        cloudWatch.deleteAlarms(request);
    }

 private static DescribeAlarmsResult describeAlarms(AmazonCloudWatch cloudWatch, String nextToken){
    DescribeAlarmsRequest request = new DescribeAlarmsRequest();
    request.withStateValue("INSUFFICIENT_DATA");
    request.withNextToken(nextToken);
    return cloudWatch.describeAlarms(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DeleteAlarms()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html#deleteAlarms-com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.DeleteAlarmsRequest-):

```
public DeleteAlarmsResult deleteAlarms(DeleteAlarmsRequest request)
```